.gitlab-ci.yml dynamic path from changed directory
Is there a way to get the directory path that the code was altered in? I want to be able to run a script that only scans that specific directory in which they were changes
stage1:
  stage: stage-name
  script:  
    - scan --path "$SCAN_PATH"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"`
  changes:
    - /example-path/**/* 
  allow_failure: true

I have tried searching multiple gitlab variables but couldn't find anything related
EDIT: changed redacted path to example

If you want to know which file was updated by using .../.../.../**/* then there's no way to directly get that information. You could create a script and filter the files by examining the diff but that's probably too much for your use case. If you need to listen to a specific directory the best way is to make changes as much specific as possible, e.g : .../.../.../my-dir/

I have a specific path, I just redacted that for the example. I will edit it to be more clear.

Thanks for the edit, I've added a possible solution hoping it helps!

There is a way to achieve this dynamically although it'll require listing the different paths available on your folder under a matrix. In GitLab there's no variable that gives you this information directly so this setup will serve as a workaround.
Taking your example, the implementation of the idea mentioned above looks like this:
stage1:
    stage: stage-name
    parallel:
    matrix:
      - SCAN_PATH: 
        - /example-subdir
        - /example-subdir2
    script:  
        - scan --path "$SCAN_PATH"
    rules:
        - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"`
          changes:
            paths:
                - /example-path/$SCAN_PATH/* 
    allow_failure: true

It'll generate a job per folder updated which will scan the specific path. If there's a folder that received no updates, the job won't trigger thanks to the rules:if:changes condition

this works, as you mentioned with the only caveat of having to adding all the possible scan paths into the matrix. I will continue to explore options but this is good progress. Thank!
